# Split video or export keynote slides separately

Tags: video, after-effects, ffmpeg, video-editor, final-cut-pro-x

I have a problem I am struggling for 2 days. Maybe someone can give me some light.
I made a huge keynote presentation (100 slides), with videos and animations. I expected to have one small exported video for each slide.  It seemed a good idea at first, but now I see I cannot export each slide separated automatically. So I tried to export all slides with the same timing in Keynote and then split in equal parts using ffmpeg, but keynote does not export the video with exact timing between slides. Then I advanced a little and tried to detect scene changes using ffmpeg (which I did and got a list of timestamps), but when splitting with ffmpeg the keyframeimage is never on the first frame making the videos unusable. Now I was searching for a solution using Mac automate, but it seems it does not have the right Keynote functions... I know that doing it manually would work, but exporting in keynote is slow and it would take hours, and maybe I will have to edit all the slides and export again. I have most of the professional video tools (final cut pro and adobe premiere/after effects.

Comment: This really looks like something that's outside the realm of the video production scope of this website.  What's inside the scope of this website includes: how you scouted and selected great locations, props, and wardrobe for your shots, how you set up the lighting, prepared your actors, managed your crew for your video clips, good microphone and sound design techniques, how you selected, edited, and graded your video clips, etc.  You have a problem with Keynote, which really isn't a video production platform.

Comment: With all due respect, if it exports video, it's producing video, so questions concerning those functions of Keynote are on-topic even if their relevance or interest to most of the audience here is low.

Comment: To the OP, can you just load the Keynote video in a video editor and then note down the slide turnover times? You can then use those times to split the video using ffmpeg in a single command.

Comment: @MichaelTiemann I am producing video, using Keynote as a tool.

Comment: @Mulvya that's seems possible at first, but there are 2 problems. First to note the slide turnover times would be manual. Second, when ffmpeg split the video, the key frame is never in the beginning, so the video starts black until the first keyframe is reached. If I ask ffmpeg to follow keyframes, it simply ignores the exact timing of the cuts and waits for the next keyframe.

Comment: My reasoning here to use keynote is simply that it is far more easier to add a logo and subtitles and keeping it consistent through videos than other video producing tool. That's why I haven't used Final cut or Premiere to create the videos, I tried, but spent triple time for each video.

Comment: And, if I change master slide, I change all slides at once. Easier to batch edit.

Comment: You'll have to re-encode the video, so the cuts will be exact.

Comment: How is this problem not solved by "playing" keynote while doing a screen capture?

Comment: @MichaelTiemann Manually capturing each slide? I want to do it automatically. Manually there are many different solutions: exporting each slide separately, for example.

Comment: I thought you said the timing of the transitions was somehow important. Now I don't think I understand at all how keynote, in this case, is being used for video production.

Comment: Your question is not really clear, but there is an option to export a keynote presentation as a .m4v file. If you then want to add more wait time in between the slides, you can add freeze frames in FCPX or Adobe Premeire.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet for splitting the video is going to be to manually razor it in a video editor of your choice.  You can then either use a clip exporter in the editing tool if it has it or export an EDL and use that with something like ffmpeg to do the splitting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a screen recorder to grab the whole presentation? Then you could import the final output into the video editor.

Comment: This answer was suggested in my second comment (see below), but the OP rejected it (for reasons I still don't understand).